# What are the ranks?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

So I started *Counter Strike Global Offensive* about two weeks ago and apparently I am on Corporal Rank 5, but when I googled the ranks, I don't see Corporal.

I am new to this game and I just want the ranks to be explained.

Answer (score 1):

I think the thing your looking for is good described in this [wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/Rank).

The rank system itself is basically used for the match making to find people with the same experience as you.

Answer (score 0):

The rank that you are talking about is your **experience level**. It is purely cosmetic, but level 3 is required to play competitive (which you have passed). After every level up you will get a drop after the match where you levelled up, up to a max of 1 drop a week per level.

When you searched for the CS:GO ranks on google, it would of most likely showed the competitive matchmaking ranks, which are a separate system specific to *competitive matches only*.